# How to set a Relative path in Rollup Macro

Tags: excel, relative-path, vba

I am using a Macro to rollup a bunch of excel files in a folder, the path is set like this:

```
MyPath = "C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\XXX\Compiled"
```

I need to set a relative path as the folder XXX keeps changing names.

I have found that

```
 Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Compiled"
```

will set a relative path, but can not figure out how to apply it to my situation, I have tried

```
 MyPath = Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Compiled"
```

but does not work

Thanks

Edit
I figured it out

```
MyPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Compiled"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you have resolved this in terms of the path of the host workbook, it may be useful to note that you can return a relative directory to the `Desktop` regardless of the `OS` by using `SpecialFolders`:

```
Dim wsShell As Object
Set wsShell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
strDir = wsShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\XXX\Compiled"
```